# How to link using -lfoo when there are versioned names of libfoo but no libfoo.so

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-library, dynamic-linking, ld

Suppose `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` contains libfoo:

- `libfoo.so.2` -> `libfoo.so.2.0.0` (symbolic link)
- `libfoo.so.2.0.0`

Notably missing is `libfoo.so`.

Suppose there is a program `/usr/local/bin/sillyprog` that compiles things using something like `gcc somefile.c -lfoo`. Every time I try to use `sillyprog`, it will fail with `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfoo` because `libfoo.so` is missing.

Assuming that I do not have permission to edit any files in `/usr`, what workarounds can I use to successfully link libfoo when running `sillyprog`?

Comment: One could also just add a library path (-L) flag when compiling, instead of an env variable. From the gcc man page, " -Ldir
           Add directory dir to the list of directories to be searched for -l."

Comment: @Faheem the advantage of the `LIBRARY_PATH` solution is that it doesn’t require being able to add arguments to the `gcc` or `ld` command-line, which would presumably require modifying `sillyprog` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create a link with the correct name to the library in a directory you control.  Then you can use the `LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables to point to this directory. These variables influence where the linker and loader look for libraries when compiling or running a program respectively. According to [the GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html):

> The value of `LIBRARY_PATH` is a colon-separated list of directories,
> much like `PATH`. When configured as a native compiler, GCC tries the
> directories thus specified when searching for special linker files, if
> it cannot find them using `GCC_EXEC_PREFIX`. Linking using GCC also
> uses these directories when searching for ordinary libraries for the
> `-l` option (but directories specified with `-L` come first).

So, something like:

```
mkdir -p ~/.local/lib
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfoo.so.2 ~/.local/lib/libfoo.so
```

And then, to run a program that uses `libfoo.so` for compilation:

```
LIBRARY_PATH=~/.local/lib sillyprog
```

Or to run a program that itself is linked to `libfoo.so`:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/.local/lib sillyprog
```